# useing xocdebuild build failed

Tags: xcodebuild

I am getting the following after building from he command line using xcodebuild, any ideas what might be wrong?

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:


    CompileC build/PackageDemo.build/Release-iphoneos/PackageDemo.build/Objects-normal/armv6/AppDelegate.o PackageDemo/AppDelegate.m normal armv6 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

    CompileC build/PackageDemo.build/Release-iphoneos/PackageDemo.build/Objects-normal/armv6/main.o PackageDemo/main.m normal armv6 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

    CompileC build/PackageDemo.build/Release-iphoneos/PackageDemo.build/Objects-normal/armv7/main.o PackageDemo/main.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

    CompileC build/PackageDemo.build/Release-iphoneos/PackageDemo.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AppDelegate.o PackageDemo/AppDelegate.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

    Ld build/PackageDemo.build/Release-iphoneos/PackageDemo.build/Objects-normal/armv6/PackageDemo normal armv6

    Ld build/PackageDemo.build/Release-iphoneos/PackageDemo.build/Objects-normal/armv7/PackageDemo normal armv7

    CreateUniversalBinary build/Release-iphoneos/PackageDemo.app/PackageDemo normal "armv6 armv7"
        GenerateDSYMFile build/Release-iphoneos/PackageDemo.app.dSYM build/Release-iphoneos/PackageDemo.app/PackageDemo
```

(8 failures)